# enqueue okhttp3 cannot resolve method java

Tags: java, android, twilio, okhttp

I'm having a bit of trouble creating an app with 2 factor authentication. I decided to use twilio as my sms gateway and decided to follow along on their tutorial. However I've run into the issue of enqueue not being able to be resolved despite having imported what I needed for it.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mTo;
private EditText mBody;
private Button mSend;
private OkHttpClient mClient = new OkHttpClient();
private Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
    mBody = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    mSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    mSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                post(mContext.getString(Integer.parseInt("http://4a61510d.grok.io/sms")), new  Callback(){

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mTo.setText("");
                                mBody.setText("");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS Sent!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
}
Call post(String url, Callback callback) throws IOException {
    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("To", mTo.getText().toString())
            .add("Body", mBody.getText().toString())
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();
    Call response = mClient.newCall(request);
    Response.**enqueue**(callback);
    return response;
}}
```

My build.gradle as well

```
 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
 {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
```

and my manifest xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I've already tried cleaning my build and restarting after invalidating my cache. ANy help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Integer.parseInt("http://4a61510d.grok.io/sms")" cause a NumberFormatException, and Response should use lowercase.

Comment: That worked but regarding "Integer.parseInt("4a61510d.grok.io/sms")" everything else seems to get me a can't resolve error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response does not have the static method enqueue so it cannot be resolved despite having imported. You need to use the object response.

```
Call response = mClient.newCall(request);
response.enqueue(callback);
return response;
```

Comment: Thanks that seemed to fix it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
response.enqueue(callback);
return response;
```

Comment: Please provide more information as to why this code will work.